# wallet seem to be encrypted or corrupt

Tags: wallet-recovery, wallet.dat, encryption

I found my wallet but i cannot access it tryed with bitcoin core. But gives error i think i encrypted or corrupted file. I openend with WinHex but only see 2020 in it.try to find hash but no succes.[image] i will upload printscreen all help with be appriced.

Comment: Your entire file seems to contain just spaces, based on that hex dump. There is no key material in there.

Comment: is it maybe encrypted? wallet.dat file is 180mb

Comment: I cannot tell based on what you're showing here.

Comment: i understand what do you need

Answer (score 0):

> **only see 2020 in it.**

Hexadecimal 20 is the ASCII space character. If your file contains nothing but 20  then it contains no useful data and no useful data can ever be extracted from it†.

> **is it maybe encrypted?**

Encrypted data generally looks like a completely random sequence of hexadecimal values between 00 and FF. If your file contains nothing other than repeats of 20, it is not encrypted.

> **wallet.dat file is 180mb**

Then I guess you might not have looked at every byte to verify that *all* are hexadecimal 20. I would use a program or script to see if somewhere in that 180 MB is any byte sequence other than repeats of hexadecimal 20. But the likelihood of recovery seems small.

- https://superuser.com/q/559772/52492 (`od -x wallet.dat | head` e.g in WSL)
- https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720458/Counting-Occurrences
- https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1159245

<sub>† you could encode a small number, e.g. 7458 as a byte and a count of repeats but this is irrelevant in the context of recovering a Bitcoin wallet file</sub>